# Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch (Java Discord bot on Heroku)

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, discord, bots

I'm making a discord bot in Java using gradle and spring boot. When I launch the application in IntelliJ IDEA it runs perfectly. It also works for the first 90 seconds before the error is thrown. I have added a Procfile, but it hasn't solved the issue. I can't see where the issue could now be.

**Code**

```
import discord4j.core.DiscordClient;
import discord4j.core.DiscordClientBuilder;
import discord4j.core.GatewayDiscordClient;
import discord4j.core.event.domain.message.MessageCreateEvent;
import discord4j.core.object.entity.Member;
import discord4j.core.object.entity.Message;
import discord4j.core.object.entity.User;
import discord4j.core.object.entity.channel.MessageChannel;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.Optional;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args){
        final GatewayDiscordClient client = DiscordClientBuilder.create("Token").build().login().block(); 
//"Token" is replaced by actual bot token in live code
        client.on(MessageCreateEvent.class).subscribe(event -> {
            final Message message = event.getMessage();
            if(message.getContent().contains("UwU")
                    || message.getContent().contains("uwu")
                    || message.getContent().contains("OwO")
                    || message.getContent().contains("owo")
                    || message.getContent().contains("UWU")
                    || message.getContent().contains("uWu")
                    || message.getContent().contains("uWU")
                    || message.getContent().contains("uwU")
                    || message.getContent().contains("UWU")
                    || message.getContent().contains("UWu")
                    || message.getContent().contains("oWo")
                    || message.getContent().contains("Owo")
                    || message.getContent().contains("owO")
                    || message.getContent().contains("OWo")
                    || message.getContent().contains("oWO")
                    || message.getContent().contains("0W0")
                    || message.getContent().contains("Onii-chan")
                    || message.getContent().contains("onii-chan")
                    || message.getContent().contains("Daijobu")
                    || message.getContent().contains("daijobu")
                    || message.getContent().contains("Nani")
                    || message.getContent().contains("nani")
                    || message.getContent().contains("Yare Yare")
                    || message.getContent().contains("yare yare")
                    || message.getContent().contains("tsundere")
                    || message.getContent().contains("Tsundere")
                    || message.getContent().contains("baka")
                    || message.getContent().contains("Baka")
                    || message.getContent().contains("Senpai")
                    || message.getContent().contains("senpai")
                    || message.getContent().contains("Yandere")
                    || message.getContent().contains("yandere")
                    || message.getContent().contains("Loli")
                    || message.getContent().contains("loli")
                    || message.getContent().contains("OWO")){
                message.delete().block();
                final MessageChannel channel = message.getChannel().block();
                channel.createMessage("NO WEEBS ALLOWED!").block();
            }
        });
        client.onDisconnect().block();
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
2021-01-19T13:28:53.204752+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
2021-01-19T13:28:53.219563+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-01-19T13:28:53.274160+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-01-19T13:28:53.314684+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

**Procfile**

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar build/libs/*.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

The Procfile configures a WebDyno which will try to bind to `PORT`, the problem is the Discord bot won't try to do that, define a background task (worker) instead

```
worker: java -jar build/libs/*.jar
```